# OpenGL program crash on Code::Blocks

Tags: c++, opengl, codeblocks

I am testing some tutorials from http://www.opengl-tutorial.org, namely the Tutorial 2: The first triangle.

My code looks like this:

```
// Include standard headers
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Include GLEW
#include "GL/glew.h"

#include "GL/gl.h"
#include "GL/glu.h"

// Include GLFW
#include "GLFW/glfw3.h"
GLFWwindow* window;

int main( void )
{
    glewInit();

    if( !glfwInit() )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "Failed to initialize GLFW\n" );
        return -1;
    }

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_SAMPLES, 4);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

    window = glfwCreateWindow(1024, 768, "Tutorial 01", NULL, NULL);
    if( window == NULL ){
        fprintf( stderr, "Failed to open GLFW window. If you have an Intel GPU, they are not 3.3 compatible. Try the 2.1 version of the tutorials.\n" );
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initialize GLEW\n");
        return -1;
    }

    glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_STICKY_KEYS, GL_TRUE);

    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.4f, 0.0f);

    GLuint vertexArrayID;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vertexArrayID);
    glBindVertexArray(vertexArrayID);

    static const GLfloat vertexArrayData[] = {
        -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
        1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
        0.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f
    };

    GLuint vertexBuffer;
    glGenBuffers(1, &vertexBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertexArrayData), vertexArrayData, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glewExperimental = true;

    do {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)0);

        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

        glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);

        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    while(glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE ) != GLFW_PRESS &&
           glfwWindowShouldClose(window) == 0 );

    glDeleteBuffers(1, &vertexBuffer);
    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &vertexArrayID);

    glfwTerminate();

    return 0;
}
```

It compiles fine, but it crashes when I try to run it. What it should do is to show white triangle on a dark blue background.

My setup & settings:

- Windows 7 Home Premium
- Intel Core i5 2.5ghz
- 4gb RAM
- Intel HD Graphics / Nvidia GT 635 M 2gb
- Code::Blocks 13.12
- GCC 4.8.1
- MinGW
- GLFW3
- GLEW 1.10.0 MINGW

Nvidia card is set as a default graphics card.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Run it under the debugger, single step it (step-over), and let us know which line it crashes on.

Comment: Seems to be the line where I call glGenVertexArrays(). Debugger says it is a segfault.

Comment: Allrighty then. Looks like my code lacked line "glewExperimental = true;" line before "if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK)". Now it does not crash, and also produces a black triangle on a dark blue background. Not entirely sure if that is purposeful, but it seems like I may have fixed the problem.

Comment: Also I have called glewInit() twice, not sure if that has something to do with it.